# References Ambiguous (Depending on project location)

Tags: vb.net, directory, ambiguous

I have a very unusual problem. My project files for Visual Basic are in:

```
C:\VB.Net\Projects
```

When they are here I have the following problems:

[image: Ambiguous errors]

In an attempt to start playing around with the references I copy / pasted the project folder to my desktop and all references were fixed ... So I tried deleting the project in  my C:\drive to re-copy it - but that didn't work...

I tried cleaning, rebuilding, setting the full namespaces (ex: AutoDesk.AutoCAD.Interop.AcadApplication) and none of that worked.

What could cause it to become unambiguous due to a directory change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a noob mistake on my part. Here's what my old references looked like during the errors:

[image]

I fixed it by removing the first AutoCAD reference.